# IBM DB2 9.7, any difference between inlined CLOB and VARCHAR?

Tags: db2, varchar, clob

Using IBM DB2 9.7, in a 32k tablespace, assuming a 10000b (ten thousand bytes) long column fits nicely in a tablespce. Is there a difference between these two, and is one preferred over the other?

```
VARCHAR(10000)
CLOB(536870912) INLINE LENGTH 10000
```

Is either or preferred in terms of functionality and performance? A quick look at the two would be that the CLOB is actually more versatile; all content shorter than 10000 is stored in stablespace, but IF bigger content is required then that is fine too, it is just stored elsewhere on disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [a number of restrictions on the way `CLOB` can be used in a query](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html):

> Special restrictions apply to expressions resulting in a CLOB data
>   type, and to structured type columns; such expressions and columns are
>   not permitted in:
>
> - A SELECT list preceded by the DISTINCT clause
> - A GROUP BY clause An ORDER BY clause A subselect of a set operator other
>     than UNION ALL
> - A basic, quantified, BETWEEN, or IN predicate
> - An aggregate function
> - VARGRAPHIC, TRANSLATE, and datetime scalar functions
> - The pattern operand in a LIKE predicate, or the search
>     string operand in a POSSTR function
> - The string representation of a
>     datetime value.

So if you need to do any of those things, `VARCHAR` is to be preferred.

I don't have a definitive answer about performance (unfortunately, information like this just doesn't seem to be in the documentation--or at least, it is not easily locatable). However, logically speaking, the DB has more work to do with a `CLOB`.  It has to decide whether to return the `CLOB` directly in the result or not. That has to mean at least some overhead. Here is [a good discussion of some of the issues](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/speeding_up_lobs61?lang=en), though it doesn't give a clear answer on performance, either.

My default position would be to use `VARCHAR` unless `CLOB` is really needed (data in the column can be bigger than the `VARCHAR` limit).